# php_serialize gem doesn't load

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use this GEM:

[PHP Serialize](https://github.com/jqr/php-serialize)

I type

```
gem install php-serialize
```

and in my main.rb Ruby app

```
require 'php_serialize'
```

The result is

```
Boot Error

Something went wrong while loading main.rb

LoadError: cannot load such file -- php_serialize
```

The environment is Sinatra, and in my main.rb I have:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sanitize'
require 'sinatra'
require 'active_record'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'
require 'pry'
require 'chronic' 
require 'json'
require 'zip'
require 'php_serialize'
```

Any idea?

**Update**

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.1.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 353) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/scrivoaroby/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
     - /Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
     - /Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin
     - /Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
     - /Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /opt/ImageMagick/bin
```

Which shotgun

```
/Users/scrivoaroby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/shotgun

    2.0.0
== Shotgun/Thin on http://127.0.0.1:9393/
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 127.0.0.1:9393, CTRL+C to stop
```

Comment: Are you using Bundler in your app? If so check you’ve added `php-serialize` to your `Gemfile`. If not can you add the result of `gem env` and `which shotgun` to your question? Also the result of running `shotgun -e "puts RUBY_VERSION" my_app.rb` might be useful (obviously change `my_app.rb` to whatever your app is called).

Comment: @matt added, I'm not using bundler

Answer (score 0):

We could use more context; the "Boot Error" is not a plain Ruby message.  What is the environment?

But when a Ruby program can't find a gem, the problem is usually one of these:

1. Ruby version less than 1.9 and you didn't `require "rubygems"` first.
2. Multiple Ruby installations and the program is using a different one from the one where you installed the gem.
3. Program is using Bundler and the gem is not in the Gemfile.
4. Gem otherwise installed in a different `$GEM_HOME` than the program is using.

Comment: is Sinatra. Any other gem is working, php_serialize fail! I added in my question the main.rb

Comment: Then I'm going to guess it's #2 or #4.  Your `gem` command didn't install `php_serialize` where your program is looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a simple script where you don't have Bundler or any other gem management system, you need to `require 'rubygems'` before requiring any gem.

In `main.rb`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'php_serialize'
```